# php setting value in multi dimensinal array depending on array of indices

Tags: php

When gathering statistical data I need to address an array with a varying number of indices.

I have to add to `$array[$ind1][$ind2]` and to `$array[$ind1][$ind2][$ind3][$ind4]`.

Is it possible to create a function  like `arrayAdd($number,$arrayOfIndices)`
where in the first case `$arrayOfIndices` is `[$ind,$ind2]`
and the second case `[$ind1,$ind2,$ind3,$ind4]`?

I solved my problem to write it all out, depending of count of `$arrayOfIndices`.

Looking however to a more elegant and generic way.

Comment: Can you please show the code you've already tried to write to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
function array_add(&$array, array $indices, $value) {
    count($indices)==1
        ? $array[$indices[0]] = $value
        : array_add($array[array_shift($indices)], $indices, $value);
}

$data = ['pig'=>'man'];
$indices = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
array_add($data, $indices, 'bat');
var_export($data);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'pig' => 'man',
  'foo' => 
  array (
    'bar' => 
    array (
      'baz' => 'bat',
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: Great solution. Thank you